# PHP Script using 1.3mb of memory, it's normal?

Tags: php

I did some tests with memory_get_usage and memory_get_peak_usage.

One of my scripts returns 1.3mb and another 1.47mb.

it's normal?

I would like to know when i need to care? how much memory.

thanks.

Comment: You start to care when your server cannot keep up with the memory demands of your concurrent users. (or slightly before that). If your server is meeting demands and seems like it will be able to scale for some time, it isn't a concern yet.

Comment: What web server do you use? One of my simple & pretty clean scripts on Apache uses between 800kB and 2MB of memory.

Comment: It's certainly not abnormal. Depending on what you're doing and how much it *should* use it may or may not be high, but in the grant scheme of things it's not.

Comment: If your loading large amounts of strings into variables or creating large arrays it will use up memory, perhaps you should unset vars that are not needed. its normal to use up 256k for a blank page no content

Comment: first, you would have to define what normal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it's normal?
```

Yes it is. It varies in the range as stated by Tadeck above.

```
I would like to know when i need to care? how much memory.
```

Ofcourse you should be caring about it when their is a need for it. How much memory doesn't have any fixed answer, however i am sure just by nitty-gitty changes in code, your memory consumption is not going to come down by much.

You must keep in mind following possible optimizations that you can make when the time come. One thing you can surely target doing is, disable all useless/unused modules inside php.ini . On my local dev box, i have about 55 modules for php enabled.

```
$ php -m | wc -l
55
```

How PHP works is, for each and every request, it will initialize 55 modules which PHP has been configured with. Each module have it's init, shutdown, cleanup steps during the lifecycle of the request, which consumes both time and memory.

For further reference you can read this post which explains all kind of internal details, which PHP request go through before printing even a simple "Hello World" on the browser.
http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2008/11/how-does-php-echos-a-hello-world-behind-the-scene/